# RobotFramework_Python_API: getting "exception" : "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException" for a post request

Tags: python, rest, post, robotframework

I am trying to execute a Post request using Python RobotFramework in Pycharm. On execution I keep getting the "exception":

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException.

Code being executed

```
TC2: Testing_createDict
    ${auth}=    Create List     Bxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxxxxx
    Create Session    mysession    ${base_url}  auth=${auth}
    ${entry}=   Create Dictionary   Lot Status Code=C   Item Number=95544403  Lot Expiration Date=09222021    Branch Plant=QIO    Lot Description=BSIC-2022-001   Lot Number=185
    ${lot master}=  Create List     ${entry}
    ${body}=    Create Dictionary   Item Lot Check (Y/N)=N      Lot Master=${lot master}
    ${header}=  Create Dictionary   Content-Type=application/json
    ${response}=    POST On Session    mysession    /jderest/orchestrator/58_XXXXX_XXXX_ORCH  data=${body}    headers=${header}
    Log To Console    ${response.status_code}
```

Output:

```
[info (+0.25s)] POST Request : url=https://xxxxx//xxx
 headers={'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.28.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '182', 'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx'} 
 body=Item+Lot+Check+%28Y%2FN%29=N&Lot+Master=Lot+Status+Code&Lot+Master=Item+Number&Lot+Master=Lot+Expiration+Date&Lot+Master=Branch+Plant&Lot+Master=Lot+Description&Lot+Master=Lot+Number 
 
[info] POST Response : url=https://xxxxxxxxx
 status=500, reason=Internal Server Error 
 headers={'Date': 'Wed, 06 Mar 2024 15:09:46 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '425', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': 'XXXXX; Expires=Wed, 13 Mar 2024 15:09:46 GMT; Path=/, AWSALBCORS=XXXXXXXXX; Expires=Wed, 13 Mar 2024 15:09:46 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure', 'X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID': 'xxx--xx-xxxx-xxxxx', 'X-ORACLE-DMS-RID': '0', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'} 
 body={
  "message" : "Unrecognized token 'Item': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN\n at [Source: (String)\"Item+Lot+Check+%28Y%2FN%29=N&Lot+Master=Lot+Status+Code&Lot+Master=Item+Number&Lot+Master=Lot+Expiration+Date&Lot+Master=Branch+Plant&Lot+Master=Lot+Description&Lot+Master=Lot+Number\"; line: 1, column: 5]",
  "exception" : "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException",
  "timeStamp" : "2024-03-06:23.09.46"
}
```

Comment: maybe change `data=${body}` to `json=${body}` on POST On Session line ?

Answer (score 0):

According to requests documentation here; https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

> If you need that header set and you don’t want to encode the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly using the json parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be encoded automatically:

That refers to setting the content type header *and* encoding of the dict into json.

In your example code, you are passing pure dict *without* encoding it to json and manually setting the content-type. This most likely leads that the actual payload uses single quote and remote parser fails with that because json standard requires double quotes.

So, your code

```
${response}=    POST On Session    mysession    /jderest/orchestrator/58_XXXXX_XXXX_ORCH  data=${body}    headers=${header}
```

Should most likely be:

```
${response}=    POST On Session    mysession    /jderest/orchestrator/58_XXXXX_XXXX_ORCH  json=${body}
```

*or*

```
${encoded_body}  Evaluate  json.dumps(${body})  modules=json
${response}=    POST On Session    mysession    /jderest/orchestrator/58_XXXXX_XXXX_ORCH  data=${body}    headers=${header}
```

Comment: I am getting the response correctly now.. with json=${body} change to the code.. Thank you..

Comment: @vineeshmohan if yes, you could mark the answer as accepted..